# azure function to convert pdf to image in node.js?

Tags: javascript, azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am trying to write an Azure function to convert pdf to image in Node.js, but not getting success. Writing directly in azure portal. Using out of the box pdf-poppler package. Here sourcepdf and targetimage are my blob containers.

Below is the code,

```
const pdf = require('pdf-poppler');
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');
const URL = require('url');


const storage = require('azure-storage');


module.exports = async function (context, myBlob) {

context.log(context.bindingData.blobTrigger);
//context.log(context.bindingData.uri);
let file = '/sourcepdf/sample.pdf';

let opts = {
    format: 'jpeg',
    out_dir: '/targetimage/sample.jpg',
    out_prefix: path.baseName(file, path.extname(file)),
    page: null
}
pdf.convert(file, opts)
    .then(res => {
        console.log('Successfully converted');
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
    })

    //context.log("JavaScript blob trigger function processed blob \n Blob:",  context.bindingData.blobTrigger, "\n Blob Size:", myBlob.length, "Bytes");
```

};

Any suggestions,

Comment: What error is being logged to the console? Is it something about file not found?

Comment: I don't think you can just write filesystem paths like that and assume they'll automatically map to Azure blob storage containers. Can pdf-poppler work with file streams or does it need files on disk? I'd guess you'd have to transfer the source file out of blob storage, process it and then upload it back again, but I don't know how temporary local files work with Azure functions.

Comment: Error I am getting is, Exception: TypeError: path.baseName is not a function

Comment: Oh, right: it's `basename` all lower case. But as above I don't think these paths will actually just work with blob storage without doing some extra work to transfer files in and out explicitly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is my work code:

```
context.log('JavaScript HTTP trigger function processed a request.');
    let file = 'D:\\home\\site\\wwwroot\\nodejs.pdf'

    let opts = {
        format: 'jpeg',
        out_dir: path.dirname(file),
        out_prefix: path.basename(file, path.extname(file)),
        page: null
    }

    pdf.convert(file, opts)
        .then(res => {
            console.log('Successfully converted');
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        })
```

Except this, you could define the output directory and file name prefix, like the `out_dir` could be `context.executionContext.functionDirectory` and the `out_prefix` just be a string like `output`. It will create the images under function folder.

[image]

Comment: await uploadLocalFile(
                        aborter,
                        destcontainerClient,
                        path.join(tarDir, file)
                      );

Comment: Hi George, this is working, now I got the files I am trying to upload the converted files to azure blob. But to upload the file to blob it has to be with async-await. Above conversion process is returning a promise. So how do we write async-await inside promise.       return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
              pdf
                .convert(sourceDirectory, opts)
            .    then((response) => {
    await uploadLocalFile(
                        aborter,
                        destcontainerClient,
                        path.join(tarDir, file)
                      );

Comment: Hi @user3432478 how do you managed to do it on azure function?

Answer (score 0):

You mention in your bounty you are looking for a function that uploads directly to a blob storage and uses async/await.

To upload directly to blob storage you want to add a [blob storage output binding](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob-output?tabs=javascript) to your function.

Your `function.json` file will look something like this:

```json
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "authLevel": "function",
      "type": "httpTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "name": "req",
      "methods": [
        "post"
      ]
    },
    {
      "type": "http",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "res"
    },
    {
      "type": "blob",
      "direction": "out",
      "name": "outBlob",
      "path": "my-container/{rand-guid}.jpg",
      "connection": "AzureWebJobsStorage"
    }
  ]
}
```

This output binding will be available in the function as `context.bindings.outBlob`;

To make synchronous methods awaitable in JavaScript, we can use the `util.promisify` function, [as is recommended by Microsoft in this example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#use-async-and-await).

Finally, to fulfill the requirements we need to read the file to memory with `fs` as the `pdf-poppler` library does not support saving a file to memory, always saving the output of the function on disk.

I have created an example Azure Function that takes a HTTP POST trigger, processes a single page PDF to an image and saves it to Azure Blob Storage.

```js
const fs = require("fs");
const fsPromises = require("fs/promises");
const util = require("util");
const pdf = require("pdf-poppler");
const os = require("os");
const path = require("path");

// Use async/await pattern as recommended by Microsoft:
// https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-reference-node?tabs=v2#use-async-and-await
const readFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.readFile);
const writeFileAsync = util.promisify(fs.writeFile);

// Trigger this function with a HTTP POST with a PDF file encoded via form-data
module.exports = async function (context, req) {
    context.log("JavaScript HTTP trigger function is processing a request.");

    if (!req.body) {
        return { status: 400, body: "No PDF file was provided!" };
    }

    // Create temp directory
    const tempPath = await fsPromises.mkdtemp(os.tmpdir() + path.sep);
    const pdfLocation = path.join(tempPath, "my-pdf.pdf");

    // Save HTTP body for further processing
    await writeFileAsync(pdfLocation, req.body, "binary");

    // Convert PDF to JPEG
    await pdf.convert(pdfLocation, {
        format: "jpg",
        out_dir: tempPath,
        out_prefix: "my-image",
        page: 1
    });

    // Read local file into memory and set as output binding
    context.bindings.outBlob = await readFileAsync(path.join(tempPath, "my-image-1.jpg"));

    return {
        status: 200,
        body: "Your PDF file has been converted to a JPEG file and uploaded to Azure Blob Storage."
    };
}
```

Make sure that when deploying to your Azure Functions app you use web deploy, or that environment variable `WEBSITE_RUN_FROM_PACKAGE` is set to `0`. [Otherwise, your file system will be read-only](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/run-functions-from-deployment-package#integration-with-zip-deployment) and the function will fail!

Being able to process multi-page PDF's is an excercise that is left up to the reader.